# Scatter plot with multiple Y axis using plotly express

Tags: python, plotly

I have to plot my data with multiple Y axis, regarding the code below I am facing several issues.

- There is no coloring is shown.
- Texts are overlapping for multiple Y axis.
- Not showing all the values of Y axis.
- On the X axis, it has to show the date such as March 10 2012 and show as much as date possible
- On one of Y axis, It has to show all the number as it is, not in the range of 50K to 100K .

how should I modify the code?

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=l1.DATE,
    y=l1.CODE,
    name="yaxis1 data",mode='markers',yaxis="y1", marker = {'color' : 'red'}

))


fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=l2.DATE,
    y=l2.CODE,
    name="yaxis2 data",mode='markers',marker = {'color' : 'blue'},

    yaxis="y2"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=l3.DATE,
    y=l3.CODE,
    name="yaxis3 data",mode='markers',marker = {'color' : 'green'},
    yaxis="y3"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=l4.DATE,
    y=l4.CODE,
    name="yaxis4 data",mode='markers',marker = {'color' : 'black'},
    yaxis="y4"
))


# Create axis objects
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        domain=[0.3, 0.7]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="yaxis title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#1f77b4"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#1f77b4"
        )
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title="yaxis2 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#ff7f0e"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#ff7f0e"
        ),
        anchor="free",
        side="left",
        position=0.15
    ),
    yaxis3=dict(
        title="yaxis3 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#d62728"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#d62728"
        ),
        anchor="x",
        side="right"
    ),
    yaxis4=dict(
        title="yaxis4 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#9467bd"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#9467bd"
        ),
        anchor="free",
        side="right",
        position=0.85
    )
)

# Update layout properties
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="multiple y-axes example",
    width=800,
)

fig.show()
```

what I produced :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fully reproduce the behavior you're seeing, but I did notice that if you are omitting the argument `overlaying="y"` in your `yaxis2, yaxis3, and yaxis4` dictionaries, the scatter data won't render in the same figure.

Here is an example similar to yours:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

l1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': ['2023-01-01','2023-01-02','2023-01-03','2023-01-04'],
    'CODE': [1,2,3,4]
})

l2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': ['2023-01-01','2023-01-02','2023-01-03','2023-01-04'],
    'CODE': [4,3,2,1]
})

l3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': ['2023-01-01','2023-01-02','2023-01-03','2023-01-04'],
    'CODE': [3,4,1,3]
})

l4 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': ['2023-01-01','2023-01-02','2023-01-03','2023-01-04'],
    'CODE': [2,1,4,4]
})

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=l1.DATE,
    y=l1.CODE,
    name="yaxis1 data",mode='markers',yaxis="y1", marker = {'color' : 'red'}

))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=l2.DATE,
    y=l2.CODE,
    name="yaxis2 data",mode='markers',marker = {'color' : 'blue'},
    yaxis="y2"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=l3.DATE,
    y=l3.CODE,
    name="yaxis3 data",mode='markers',marker = {'color' : 'green'},
    yaxis="y3"
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=l4.DATE,
    y=l4.CODE,
    name="yaxis4 data",mode='markers',marker = {'color' : 'black'},
    yaxis="y4"
))


# Create axis objects
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        domain=[0.3, 0.7]
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title="yaxis title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#1f77b4"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#1f77b4"
        ),
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title="yaxis2 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#ff7f0e"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#ff7f0e"
        ),
        anchor="free",
        overlaying="y",
        side="left",
        position=0.15
    ),
    yaxis3=dict(
        title="yaxis3 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#d62728"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#d62728"
        ),
        anchor="x",
        overlaying="y",
        side="right"
    ),
    yaxis4=dict(
        title="yaxis4 title",
        titlefont=dict(
            color="#9467bd"
        ),
        tickfont=dict(
            color="#9467bd"
        ),
        anchor="free",
        overlaying="y",
        side="right",
        position=0.85
    )
)

# Update layout properties
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="multiple y-axes example",
    width=800,
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but except coloring, all remains the same and no imrovement ..

Comment: What happens if you run my sample code? Do you get the same result?